# Percentual dynamic bandwidth control

Tags: networking, tc, qos, mobile

Does anyone know a tool that can percentually divide the **currently available** bandwidth? We're on a GPRS connection on which the available bandwidth changes frequently. What I want to achieve is the following:

- Egress to port x: 60% of available bandwidth
- Egress to port y: 30% of available bandwidth
- All other egress traffic: 10% of available bandwidth

With tc (iproute2) I managed to achieve something in this direction by using an htb qdisc, and creating 3 classes with a rate of 60 / 30 / 10 kbps. By using a ceiling of 100kbs the classes would use any available bandwidth under 100kbs if available, but never more.

This kind of statically configured bandwidth is however not a solution that would work for us, since our bandwidth is extremely variable and we don't want to configure a ceiling. Our goal is to use the available bandwidth as much as possible. Ideally, we do not want to configure a rate in bytes/seconds but in a percentage. Is this be possible? I looked a the prio qdisc but the documentation there is really lacking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`tc` can do a lot more than the standard example of traffic shaping on an ADSL line that originates from the [Linux Advanced Routing And Traffic Shaping HOWTO](http://lartc.org). It is true that the canonical example works best with a statically-configured bandwidth, but that doesn't mean it's the only thing `tc` can configure. That HOWTO is fairly extensive, and will probably get you on the way; if not, a more detailed explanation of what you want to get done would seem to be in order.

At any rate, since `tc` is just a configuration tool for the actual traffic shaping subsystem in the kernel the kernel, if `tc` can't do it, nothing can.

Comment: Hi Wouter, I just updated the question, it would be great if you could take another look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research it is clear that dividing the available bandwidth percentually is not possible. There is no way for the system to know the currently available bandwidth.